# HttpGet not recognizing url

Tags: java, android, html, syntax, apache-commons-httpclient

So I'm using the code below from a different older post, but having trouble with one part, the line for: `HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);` doesn't work. In the url spot I put something like `www.stackoverflow.com`, but that one part won't let the code compile. I'm basically trying to pull text writing from an html website. The complete code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(www.stackoverflow.com);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    String html = "Toronto-GTA";
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        str.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();
}
```

Comment: for HttpGet request = new HttpGet(www.stackoverflow.com); i changed it to ("www.stackoverflow.com"); as many had suggested, but other lines such as "HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);" return compile errors, all of them: unhandled exception type IOException, most of the quick fixes in eclipse suggest "Surroned with try/catch"

Answer (score 3):

[HTTPGet](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) expects an [URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html) or a string, so try to change your request line into:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a string of the form:

```
[scheme:][//authority][path][?query][#fragment]
```

i.e. `"http://www.stackoverflow.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `HttpGet request = new HttpGet("www.stackoverflow.com");`

Comment: I tried changing it so the url has "", but this causes lines like : "HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);", "InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();", and a couple more to error out instead.

Comment: Does "error out" mean compile errors or runtime exceptions?  If it's an exception, please post it.

Comment: compile errors, all of them: unhandled exception type IOException, most of the quick fixes in eclipse suggest "Surroned with try/catch"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above given answers surround your code with try and catch statements to catch the exceptions.

```
try{
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("www.stackoverflow.com");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line, html = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        str.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();
}
catch(Exception e){
//Do something here like printing the stacktrace
}
```